# Unreal Engine Animation Won't Transition Back to Initial State In Animation Blueprint

Tags: animation, blender, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm making a 3rd person shooter game, and I have a sword weapon. I have an animation for it, and I transition into the animation from my idle/walking/running state in my animation blueprint. It should transition back to the idle blend space, right? But, when it transitions back, the idle animation doesn't play. I just get a static pose.  How can I fix this? Below, I've attached code for my character blueprint, animation blueprint, etc.
[image: overview of animation blueprint]

[image: Transition between the idle and sword animations]

[image: Transition back to the blend space]

[image: Idle blendspace in the animation blueprint]

[image: Animation blueprint eventgraph]

[image: Setting the variable to change the animation in the character blueprint]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the time remaining ratio to less than 0.1 or 0.9

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Get Relevant Anim Time Remaining node and check if it's less than one for the transition rule.

Comment: I figured it out. It actually wasn't a problem with the transition, but the animation event graph. Thanks anyway!